# Real Analysis Stephen Abbott 3.2.2.c self study question.

Tags: real-analysis

A = $\{(-1)^n + \frac{2}{n}: n=1,2,3,\cdots\}$ it seems to me all points in the set are isolated since the only limit points are 1 and -1 and they are not in the set.  So now every point remaining is NOT a limit point of the set, and hence by Definition 3.2.6 all are isolated.

Now for set B = $ \{x\in\mathbb{Q}:0<x<1\}$ it seems like there are no isolated points because you could build a sequence of rationals to approach any real number including another rational number.  I'm not 100% solid on that but for example consider $a_n = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4n}$ or any similar sequence creating a limit point out of a member of that set.  I think maybe I'm missing something critical about what defines a 'limit point'?

Comment: $\;1=(-1)^1+\frac21\;\ldots\;$

Comment: oops.  I missed that point.  So for A all points except 1 are isolated.  Thanks.

Comment: No, not quite...You may want to check elements of $\;A\;$ for even $\;n\;$ , and then for odd $\;n\;$ .

Comment: A limit point of a set $S$ has the property that any epsilon neighborhood around the point contains some other element of $S$. This coupled with the density of the rationals in the reals should be enough for B.